# Cmake can not find ZLIB on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: compiling, 20.04, cmake, zlib

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows Subsystem for linux. Cmake is version 3.16.3.
I am trying to build a project with a zlib dependency, and I get the following error...

```
 Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY) (found version "1.2.11")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindZLIB.cmake:115 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:1224 (find_package)
```

Package zlib1g is installed.

How can I rectify this?

Comment: `found version "1.2.11"` suggests it **is** finding the installed library, but it wants a different version

Comment: I got this error and the reason turned out to be wholly unrelated. Some folders were missing their CMakeLists.txt files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in CMake: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/20127.

Answer (score 1):

My workaround for this issue was to include the library in the command line, like this:

```
cmake -DZLIB_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so  ..
```

Comment: I had the same problem on MSYS2. My workaround was `cmake -DZLIB_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/libz.dll.a ..`

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar issue compiling https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-cpp/tree/master/examples/s3 on Ubuntu 22.04 or Amazon Linux 2023.
I resolved it by adding in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED "1.0")
```

Found here: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/7475